# How do I extract a google sheet named range's column number via Google Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, named-ranges

I need to enter data in a Google sheet cell, which cell is in a named range. To do that using a Google Script, I need to know the named range's column number. I have written a script that gets the job done, but only because I know the named range has only one column, so I use the getLastColumn command to get the column number. I know there has to be a command to "getColumnNumber" or something like that, but from Google documentation and this site, I simply can't find it. Any help? Bound script below:

```
function addSong() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()
    sheet.appendRow([lastRow+1]);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    var range = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 1);
    var songTitle = Browser.inputBox('New Song', 'Enter the song title', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
    var namedRange = sheet.getRange("Title");
    var col = namedRange.getLastColumn();
    sheet.getRange([lastRow+1], col).setValue(songTitle)
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveRange(range);
}
```

Hey Cooper:  I tried your approach and it works great, except it loses some of what I was doing with my script; specifically, it does not increment the song record number. So, I added the key bit from what you did to get the named range column correctly into my code and it all works. Revised code is:

```
function addSong() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()
    sheet.appendRow([lastRow+1]);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    var range = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 1);
    var songTitle = Browser.inputBox('New Song', 'Enter the song title', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
    var namedRange = sheet.getRange("Title");
    var range=sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), namedRange.getColumn())
    range.setValue(songTitle);
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveRange(range);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function addSong() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var resp=SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt('New Song', 'Enter the sone title', SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  var songTitle=resp.getResponseText();
  var namedRange = ss.getRangeByName('Title');
  var range=sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1, namedRange.getColumn())
  range.setValue(songTitle);
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveRange(range);
}
```

- [range.column documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getColumn())